# Why is my model's feet going through his shoes?

Tags: rigging, vertices

I have a Sonic model from Sketchfab that I am trying to rig. Whenever I try to automatic weight my bones to the model, I grab his "torso bone" and move it downward but whenever I do that his feet will get very distorted.

[Short video demonstrating the problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvktsok87cxp9rg/sonic_rig_feet.mp4?dl=0)

How do I fix this?

Edit: [Here's my Blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/amlptwd1m79fup3/Sonic_The_Hedgehog_rig_feet_problem.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Hi, it is because of the weight painting not being done properly

Comment: Thanks, do you have any more information/links you could give me to help me learn how to do it properly?